# Safari web extension manfiest.json bug

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, safari-extension, web-extension, safari-web-extension

This is my chrome `manifest.json` file and it works perfectly fine for chrome, but when i **convert** the **chrome** extension to **safari** **extension** using `xcrun safari-web-extension-converter ./my-chrome-extension/dist` it gives this **warning**

> **Warning**: The following keys in your `manifest.json` are not supported by your current version of Safari. If these are critical to your extension, you should review your code to see if you need to make changes to support Safari:
>
> **type** 
> **use_dynamic_url**

Safari version : **17.1.2**

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Popup",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icons/icon16.png",
    "32": "assets/icons/icon32.png",
    "48": "assets/icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "assets/icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "description": "My description.",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background/background.js"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["assets/placeholder/image_placeholder.jpg"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script/src/main.tsx"]
    }
  ]
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "react-content-script",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-shadow-root": "^6.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@crxjs/vite-plugin": "@crxjs/vite-plugin@2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.197",
    "@types/node": "^18.8.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "crx-hotreload": "^1.0.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.0",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Any documentation, any reference, any solution which could fix this problem would of great help!

Thank you.

Comment: It's [not yet implemented in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1383176) so there's no point in using it. Your manifest.json doesn't contain this key, which means it's a bug in Safari converter.